# TinyMCE Visual Editor Won't Save, PlainText Does?

Tags: wordpress, tinymce

I have TinyMCE in my Wordpress plugin, and have been having a super irritating problem with TinyMCE. It will save edits made in plaintext mode but won't save edit made in Visual mode (and throws an error).

This is the code I use to create the TinyMCE textarea. I name the field correctly to save and load from options.php (which works when it's just a plain textarea).

```
$x_options = get_option('editbox');
/*HTML form fields*/
$rc_initial_data = ( isset( $x_options['fluid_body'] ) ) ?$x_options['fluid_body']:'';
$settings = array( 'wpautop' => true, 'textarea_name' => 'editbox[fluid_body]', 'quicktags' => true, 'tinymce' => true, 'quicktags' => array('buttons' => 'em,strong,link,block,ul,ol,li,p,close,spell,img') );
wp_editor( $rc_initial_data, 'fluid_body', $settings );
```

The error I get is this:

```
Can't create duplicate variable: 'typeMap'
```

The error is in wp-tinymce.php (which loads a .js file). I use multiple TinyMCE-enabled fields, but they are all named uniquely so the "duplicate" thing shouldn't be a problem (and isn't, if it's plaintext).

Any ideas why the Visual editor isn't working? Everything is the current version, Wordpress, jQuery, etc.

Comment: What browser and OS are you using?

Comment: I've tested it in Safari and Chrome, a big enough audience it's a problem. :(

Comment: I believe its is a known issue that Safari throws this error when loading TinyMCE (it happens even loading the TinyMCE demo on the TinyMCE web site) but I am not aware of it causing the editor to malfunction. I cannot get the error to appear when loading TinyMCE in Chrome.